# CSS: How can I change background of a child in response to a hover event on parent?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this case where I have a `<span>` element containing text `AND`. The `<span>` has a `background: black`.

On hovering its `.parent` class, I want background of the span to match that of the parent when `.parent` is hovered (i.e. `#eee`).

I read about `:host-context` and used it as shown in snippet below but it is not seem to be working. I even used SCSS in jsfiddle ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/usmanajmal/x3kmfnru/)) but still no luck.

Is there a way to set background of child `.text` when the parent or great grand parent `.parent` is hovered?

```css
.line {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
}
.text {
    color: green;
    background: black;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.parent {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height:100px;
}


.parent:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

:host-context(.parent:hover) {
  .text {
    background: #eee;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <div class="line" style="">
    <span class="text">AND</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.parent:hover .text` as a selector: It is applied to `.text` within `.parent` when `.parent` is hovered.

```css
.line {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    line-height: 0.1em;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0 20px;
}
.text {
    color: green;
    background: black;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.parent {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height:100px;
}


.parent:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.parent:hover .text {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <div class="line" style="">
    <span class="text">AND</span>
  </div>
</div>
```